# Child elements are outside parent footer element

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my `<footer>`. Any child element of the `<footer>` will placed outside of it.

How do I put child elements inside the `<footer>` and align the child from left to right?

```css
footer{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}
footer > a,
#link{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#damn{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="link">
      here we go again
    </div>
  </a>
  <div id="damn">
  </div>
  why the hell
</footer>
```

Comment: Some people do not appreciate swearing...

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when the content is bigger than the height you set?

Comment: I have no idea about "swearing" lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display flex property should be given to parent element so that child will be aligned accordingly to property for align-items (cross axis) and justify-contents (main axis).

```
footer{
      background-color: black;
      height: 100px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: You should post a snippet with your answer

Comment: btw, I don't use the `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have the heights of all your elements set to 100px - so your A tag fills up all the height of your footer, and your "damn" tag has nowhere to go but below the footer.

Edit:  OK, so you want the elements left-to-right inside the footer.  Give the footer's immediate children `display:inline-block`.  You can put `display:flex` on the div div inside the A tag.

Comment: But I want the footer to be fixed `100px`

Comment: OK, so you want the elements left-to-right inside the footer?  Give the footer's immediate children display:inline-block. You can put display:flex on the div div inside the A tag.